# Calling an object of template class

Tags: c++, templates

I [found this code online](http://shiftedbits.org/2011/01/30/cubic-spline-interpolation/), it implements the Cubic Spline Interpolation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/** Templated on type of X, Y. X and Y must have operator +, -, *, /. Y must have defined
* a constructor that takes a scalar. */
template <typename X, typename Y>
class Spline 
{
public:
    /** An empty, invalid spline */
    Spline() {}

    /** A spline with x and y values */
    Spline(const vector<X>& x, const vector<Y>& y) 
    {
        if (x.size() != y.size()) {cerr << "X and Y must be the same size " << endl; return;}
        if (x.size() < 3) { cerr << "Must have at least three points for interpolation" << endl; return;}

        typedef typename vector<X>::difference_type size_type;

        size_type n = y.size() - 1;

        vector<Y> b(n), d(n), a(n), c(n + 1), l(n + 1), u(n + 1), z(n + 1);
        vector<X> h(n + 1);

        l[0] = Y(1);
        u[0] = Y(0);
        z[0] = Y(0);
        h[0] = x[1] - x[0];

        for (size_type i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            h[i] = x[i + 1] - x[i];
            l[i] = Y(2 * (x[i + 1] - x[i - 1])) - Y(h[i - 1]) * u[i - 1];
            u[i] = Y(h[i]) / l[i];
            a[i] = (Y(3) / Y(h[i])) * (y[i + 1] - y[i]) - (Y(3) / Y(h[i - 1])) * (y[i] - y[i - 1]);
            z[i] = (a[i] - Y(h[i - 1]) * z[i - 1]) / l[i];
        }

        l[n] = Y(1);
        z[n] = c[n] = Y(0);

        for (size_type j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
        {
            c[j] = z[j] - u[j] * c[j + 1];
            b[j] = (y[j + 1] - y[j]) / Y(h[j]) - (Y(h[j]) * (c[j + 1] + Y(2) * c[j])) / Y(3);
            d[j] = (c[j + 1] - c[j]) / Y(3 * h[j]);
        }

        for (size_type i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            mElements.push_back(Element(x[i], y[i], b[i], c[i], d[i]));
        }
    }
    virtual ~Spline() {}

    Y operator[](const X& x) const {return interpolate(x);}

    Y interpolate(const X&x) const 
    {
        if (mElements.size() == 0) return Y();

        typename std::vector<element_type>::const_iterator it;
        it = lower_bound(mElements.begin(), mElements.end(), element_type(x));
        if (it != mElements.begin()) {it--;}

        return it->eval(x);
    }

    vector<Y> operator[](const vector<X>& xx) const {return interpolate(xx);}

    /* Evaluate at multiple locations, assuming xx is sorted ascending */
    vector<Y> interpolate(const vector<X>& xx) const {
        if (mElements.size() == 0) return vector<Y>(xx.size());

        typename vector<X>::const_iterator it;
        typename vector<element_type>::const_iterator it2;
        it2 = mElements.begin();
        vector<Y> ys;
        for (it = xx.begin(); it != xx.end(); it++) 
        {
            it2 = lower_bound(it2, mElements.end(), element_type(*it));
            if (it2 != mElements.begin()) {it2--;}

            ys.push_back(it2->eval(*it));
        }

        return ys;
    }

protected:

    class Element {
    public:
        Element(X _x) : x(_x) {}
        Element(X _x, Y _a, Y _b, Y _c, Y _d)
            : x(_x), a(_a), b(_b), c(_c), d(_d) {}

        Y eval(const X& xx) const 
        {
            X xix(xx - x);
            return a + b * xix + c * (xix * xix) + d * (xix * xix * xix);
        }

        bool operator<(const Element& e) const {return x < e.x;}
        bool operator<(const X& xx) const {return x < xx;}

        X x;
        Y a, b, c, d;
    };

    typedef Element element_type;
    vector<element_type> mElements;
};
```

I am calling it like this:

```
Spline<VecDoub, VecDoub> MySpline(VecDoub(t), VecDoub(x));
```

But although the program compiles without errors, the function isn't called at all. What's wrong? I am not an expert in OO C++...

Comment: What's VecDoub? There's no sign of it :|

Comment: You are defining a function called `MySpline` that takes two `VecDoub` parameters (read up on the most vexing parse).

Comment: I would assume the Spline function should be called, i.e. my parameters passed to it. I know because I put a breakpoints inside it and run debug mode (MS Visual Studio Express 2013) but it just continue running normally (I'm using it inside a larger program).

VecDoub defines a vector...

Comment: You assume incorrectly, as I said you need to read about the most vexing parse.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
Spline<VecDoub, VecDoub> MySpline(VecDoub(t), VecDoub(x));
```

Defines a function that takes two `VecDoub` parameters and returns a `Spline<VecDoub, VecDoub>` (`VecDoub(t)` is the same as writing `VecDoub t` in this case)

If your compiler supports uniform initialization you can use

```
Spline<VecDoub, VecDoub> MySpline{VecDoub(t), VecDoub(x)};
```

Perhaps even

```
Spline<VecDoub, VecDoub> MySpline(t, x);
```

will work depending on what types `t` and `x` are.

Comment: I get this error with the first implementation:
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'Spline<VecDoub,VecDoub>'

Comment: What version of VS are you using, what is `VecDoub`, and what are `t` and `x`?

Comment: VS Express 2013; VecDoub is defined in nr3.h as:
typedef NRvector<Doub> VecDoub;
and t and x are vectors of type VecDoub.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector<VecDoub> v1;
Vector<VecDoub> v2;

Spline<VecDoub,VecDoub> mySpline(v1,v2);
```

or

```
Spline<VecDoub,VecDoub> mySpline(Vector<VecDoub>(),Vector<VecDoub>());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm assuming that `VecDoub` is `std::vector<double>`, but anyway, what you posted is the constructor of the class.

Comment: So how would I call the function Spline within that class?